# node2nix override; wrapProgram: command not found

Tags: nix, nixos, nixpkgs

I'm packaging a node script with an external dependency (GraphicsMagick), and when attempting to override the derivation generated from `node2nix` I get the error:

> wrapProgram: command not found

The following text goes into detail of what I've tried to solve this error.

---

### Reproducing the problem from scratch

I've created a [minimal git repository](https://r.querie.cc/a) that reproduces this problem if you'd just like to take a look there. Else, the steps to reproduce the problem are below.

#### Initial Shell Session:

In an empty directory, run:

```sh
npm init -y
npm install --save gm
curl https://i.imgur.com/addSfQi.jpg > image.png
```

(`npm version: 5.6.0` & `node version v8.9.4`)

#### Create `index.js`

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const path = require("path"); // node.js builtin
const gm = require("gm"); // GraphicsMagick module

const imagePath = path.join(__dirname, "image.png");

// Flip image horizontally and write to disk
gm(imagePath)
  .flop()
  .write(imagePath, error => {
    console.log("error:", error);
  });
```

#### Add a "bin" section to package.json:

```
"bin": "index.js"
```

#### Generate *.nix files with `node2nix`

```sh
node2nix -8 -l package-lock.json
```

#### Create `override.nix`

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {}
, system ? builtins.currentSystem
}:

let
  nodePackages = import ./default.nix {
    inherit pkgs system;
  };
in
nodePackages // {
  package = nodePackages.package.override (oldAttrs: {
    postInstall = ''
      wrapProgram "$out/bin/test-nodejs-gm-nixpkg" --prefix PATH : "${pkgs.graphicsmagick}/bin"
    '';
  });
}
```

#### Build nix package

```
nix-build override.nix -A package
```

The above fails with:

> /nix/store/*/setup: line 95: wrapProgram: command not found

---

### Helpful Resources

- [node2nix git repository](https://github.com/svanderburg/node2nix) - includes some basic examples.
- [example override in nixpkgs](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/c4bb4252cb351dae91797bf32186697a836ebadb/pkgs/development/node-packages/default-v8.nix#L13) - example of how nixpkgs uses `wrapProgram` in `postInstall` with files generated by `node2nix`.

Comment: I believe you want to add `nativeBuildInputs = oldAttrs.nativeBuildInputs or [] ++ [ pkgs.makeWrapper ]` within your override to make `wrapProgram` available.

Comment: @ppb Adding `nativeBuildInputs = [ pkgs.makeWrapper ];` solved it. If you throw your comment into an answer I'll accept it. Also: If you don't mind me asking, where can I learn more about this? Thanks!

Comment: @x9hb8wcy6quezjk `makeWrapper` is covered in the [nixpkgs manual](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#ssec-stdenv-functions) and the [source](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/tree/master/pkgs/build-support/setup-hooks) is within the `build-support` directory of the repo.

Answer (score 6):

`wrapProgram` is contained within the `makeWrapper` package.

```
nativeBuildInputs = oldAttrs.nativeBuildInputs or [] ++ [ pkgs.makeWrapper ];
```

As mentioned by @ppb in the comments.